# Global solar radiation data

Tags: data, spatial-database, asia

I need a solar radiation data in central Asia. Is there any global dataset of solar radiation?

If someone know about it, please send to me the link.

Comment: what format are you looking for? JPEG Images, tabular data, KML?

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/3f4odjj

Answer (score 4):

Do you know [soDa services](http://www.soda-is.com/eng/index.html) ? You should see if they provide geo-localized data for registered users. From what I know, they don't do it for free.

By the way, you can get it from grass using r.sun : http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/r.sun.html

Answer (score 3):

If you want spatiotemporal data of historical/gridded global solar radiation, you can check out the [NCEP/NCAR Reanalysis](https://web.archive.org/web/20111223131946/http://dss.ucar.edu:80/pub/reanalysis/) datasets (e.g., [other flux](https://psl.noaa.gov/data/gridded/data.ncep.reanalysis.html)). The data spans from 1948–2010, and you can get a variety of time resolutions (e.g., daily, monthly, etc.). The spatial resolution is coarse (as it is global) and the format is GRIB or NetCDF, which you can read/process with [GDAL](https://gdal.org/frmt_grib.html), [NCL](https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/) or other software.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you mean by 'global' in this context, but U. Colorado's [Laboratory for Atmospheric and Space Physics](http://lasp.colorado.edu/)' [Interactive Solar IRradiance Datacenter](http://lasp.colorado.edu/lisird/) has a number of irradiance products, including total solar irradiance.

Most of their data is from spacecraft, so they measure the change in output of the sun, not necessarily how much reaches the ground in a given region.

Answer (score 1):

Solargis released a set of solar resource data: yearly long-term averages, 30 arc-sec pixel (~1 km), free to download ([CC BY 3.0 IGO](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/igo/) licence), all metadata included.

It is published via **[GlobalSolarAtlas](http://globalsolaratlas.info/downloads/world)** or downloadable from **[Solargis](https://solargis.com/maps-and-gis-data/download/)** website, downloadable per country or complete World dataset.
Data is ready-to-use in GIS, two formats are available:

- GeoTIFF
- ESRI ASCII Grid